# BigQuery clustering column recommendations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there any out-of-box solution to get the possible recommendations for the partitioned table to choose the clustered column?

For example, I have a partitioned table with 50 columns and there are a lot of different queries landing on those tables, ie - different types of queries in where clause. So I am wondering if there is any out-of-box solution to see the recommendation from BigQuery end to say enabling col5,col6 as cluster column might reduce the cost by x% and increase y% of performance improvement by getting the query usage from logs or by ML feature from usage for certain window (some thing like [this ML feature](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/google-cloud-launches-bigquery-capacity-recommendations))?

One of the options is to manually find using a trial and error approach on different columns by verifying the query logs, but definitely, that is time-consuming so keeping this as the last option, and I have around 20 tables and each table has around 50 to 100 columns so trying to get rid of this option.

Comment: Hey, it's a good recommendation idea!! And it's not implemented (I don't know what it is in the roadmap). However, most of the time, the partition/cluster are related to your business and the data usage, but observing the BQ behavior and making recommendation is a great idea!

Comment: `However, most of the time, the partition/cluster are related to your business and the data usage` - That's correct, that why I wanted to make use of query logs or any other based on the history. Of course we can't predict for the future usages as entirely it depends on business and its frequent drifts! If it is something available with the current usage trend then it is more than enough and we can change (by recreating the table) whenever there is huge changes in the query usage!

Comment: my current problem with clustering is the ordering part. If we have clusters by: col1, col2, col3, then gbq will sort with col1 first , col2 next within col1 and col3 within col2 data. so if someone does where condition with anything other than col1 in it like col2=something then clustering is not as effective as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendations for the clustering and partitions are in Pre-GA now - Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/new-bigquery-partitioning-and-clustering-recommendations/) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/apply-partition-cluster-recommendations)